# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'abrir_conexion'

Tags: php

Intento conectar mi web a mi servidor de base de datos, pero me da error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'abrir_conexion' in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog03\index.php:95 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog03\index.php on line 95, este para ser especifico.

Este es el código *PHP* que he usado para hacerlo:

```
public static function abrir_conexion() {
        if(!isset(self::$conexion)){
            try {
                include_once 'config.inc.php';
                self::$conexion=new PDO("mysql:host=$nombre_servidor; dbname=$nombre_base_datos, $nombre_usuario, $password");
                self::$conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$conexion -> exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
                
                print "Conexion Abierta";
                
            } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                print "ERROR" . $ex -> getMessage(). '<br>';
                die();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

---

aqui esta mas explicado lo que pasa, saludos y gracias por responder.

class Conexion {

```
private static $conexion;

public static function abrir_conexion() {
    if (!isset(self::$conexion)) {
        try {
            include_once 'config.inc.php';
            self::$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$nombre_servidor; dbname=$nombre_base_datos", $nombre_usuario, $password);
            self::$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

            print "Conexion Abierta";
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            print "ERROR: " . $ex->getMessage() . '<br>';
            die();
        }
    }
}

public static function cerrar_conexion() {
    if (isset(self::$conexion)) {
        self::$conexion = null;
        print "Conexion Cerrada";
    }
}

public static function obtener_conexion() {
    return self::$conexion;
}
```

}

```
 include_once 'app/Conexion.inc.php';#Este es el include en el index que parece no funcionar.             
  Conexion :: abrir_conexion;
  Conexion :: cerrar_conexion;
```

Todo esto me da el siguiente error.
Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'abrir_conexion' in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog03\index.php:95 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog03\index.php on line 95

Comment: ¿Este código existe dentro de alguna clase? de ser así por favor verifica y de ser posible añade esa sección por que ahi indica que una constante que tratas de usar esta indefinida

Comment: muestranos config.inc.php porfavor.

Comment: Verifica en C:\xampp\htdocs\blog03\index.php que estés usando los paréntesis para llamar a la función abrir_conexion

Comment: Tu error es muy simple, te falta colocar los parántesis cuando invocas a `abrir_conexion` debe quedar así: `Conexion :: abrir_conexion();`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que está interpretando abrir_conexion como una constante y no como una función.

Al igual que las variables van precedidas por **`$`**, las funciones tienen paréntesis **`()`** aunque no tengan ningún parámetro. Las constantes de usuario son aquellas que no tienen nada.

Si sigues el mensaje de error y te vas a la línea indicada podrás ver que hay una constante con ese nombre, en este ejemplo que nos has puesto yo diría que es la parte de:

```
Conexion::abrir_conexion;
```

Como puedes ver abrir conexión no está seguido de su paréntesis, por tanto prueba a ponerlo como:

```
Conexion::abrir_conexion();
```

No se si resolverá todo, pero seguramente resuelva este problema para esta línea en concreto. Deberías aplicar esto en todos los sitios similares.